# Ignoring a number of characters stored in a variable while using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code i need to extract doubles and string from a line formated like this  **"[double,double] string"** with the string starting as a first non white character and any number of white characters after **[**

I do care about loading properly the numbers, but don't care about the string (could even be empty).

```
char *read;
size_t len=0;
double x,y;
int size;

getline(&read,&len,stdin);
char *name=(char*)malloc(strlen(read));
if(sscanf(read,"[ %lf, %lf ] %n",&x,&y,&size)!=2)
{
return 0;
} 
sscanf(read,"%*.c%[^\n]s",size,name);
```

I already have implemented everything. I know that the second sscanf cannot work like this, only there to represent my thought. Is there any way how to get the size variable to be a parameter of how many characters not to load? I searched everything and the only thing i could find was to have number defined, which does not help here.

Also I am quite new to programming, so please be considerate about me not knowing maybe basic stuff.

Comment: You can use `sprintf` to build the format string for `sscanf`.

Comment: Is the `getline` you use something you wrote yourself? Edit: Found it, `POSIX.1-2008`

Comment: Seems like all `C` to me.

Comment: I use it to automatically dynamically allocate the "read" pointer array. I got a bit of help implementing it.

Comment: @VincentJakl -- I am sure C++ has all of the facilities without any manual memory management or hard-to-decipher `sscanf` calls.

Comment: `scanf` actually has built-in `malloc` support - but since this is aimed at C++, try to avoid `scanf`, the Posix `getline` and `malloc` - or change the tag to `C`.

Comment: @VincentJakl Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), with the difference being we know what the "X" is.  So are you writing C++ code, or C code?

Comment: Sorry it is in C

Comment: `getline` returns the number of characters read, there is no need to call `strlen` again. Just **check** and **use the return** of `getline()`. Why not `sscanf (read, " [%lf,%lf ] %[^\n]", &x, &y, name) == 3`? There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and technically you want `malloc(strlen(read) + 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question and you want to separate, e.g. `"[123.456, 789.34] Daffy Duck"` into the two doubles and the name using `getline` and `sscanf` allocating storage for `name`, then a single call to POSIX `getline()` and a single call to `sscanf` reading name into a temporary array and then allocating and copying to `name` will allow you to size `name` exactly as required.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 1024

int main (void) {

    double x, y;
    char *read = NULL, *name = NULL, tmp[MAXN];
    size_t n = 0;

    fputs ("input: ", stdout);
    if (getline (&read, &n, stdin) == -1) {
        fputs ("error: getline.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf (read, " [%lf ,%lf ] %1023[^\n]", &x, &y, tmp) == 3) {
        size_t len = strlen (tmp);
        if (!(name = malloc (len + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc-name");
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy (name, tmp, len + 1);

        printf ("x   : %f\ny   : %f\nname: %s\n", x, y, name);
        free (name);
    }
    free (read);
}
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Also note that when the parameter `n = 0` as above, `getline()` will allocate storage as needed to handle your input line. So following the call to `getline()`, `read` has allocated storage duration. You will need to free `read` to avoid leaking memory and you cannot simply return a pointer to the beginning of `name` within `read` as you must preserve a pointer to the beginning of `read` in order to be able to `free` it.

**Example Use/Output**

Then by including appropriate whitespace in your `sscanf` *format-string* you can flexibly read your input regardless of leading or intervening whitespace, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/readxyname
input: [123.456, 789.34] Daffy Duck
x   : 123.456000
y   : 789.340000
name: Daffy Duck
```

With no whitespace in input:

```
$ ./bin/readxyname
input: [123.456,789.34]Daffy Duck
x   : 123.456000
y   : 789.340000
name: Daffy Duck
```

With arbitrary whitespace in input:

```
$ input:  [        123.456    ,        789.34  ]           Daffy Duck
x   : 123.456000
y   : 789.340000
name: Daffy Duck
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped `:)`  Know there are many many ways to do this. The use of `sscanf` here is probably one of the easier ones. So long as you understand that carefully including whitespace in your *format-string* allows `sscanf` to ignore the whitespace -- which allows you a really flexible way to handle this set of doubles and a name. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` may ignore matches with the `*` formatter. More on that on conversion specifications [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). That way, you can match and store double and match and ignore the following string i.e. `%*s`.

A bit easier way could be searching for `]` with i.e. `strchr` and then passing `sscanf` only the string portion you're actually interested in (now that you know where it begins and ends) through simple pointer arithmetics.